# What is a good string height for a mountain dulcimer?

Tags: maintenance, lutherie

27" scale, tuned DAd.

Just ordered the nut and saddle and don't know how much I should sand them down as I'm not really a dulcimer player.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optimal string height for a mountain dulcimer won't be radically different than for any other fretted instrument. It is at least partly a matter of personal preference. In general:

- The string height will need to be high enough that you can play a note on any fret without buzz
- If you tend to play hard, you will need to increase the string height. If you are a more gentle player, you can go with a lower height

[This article](https://www.harpkit.com/mm5/pdf/Instructions/HOURKIT.pdf) deals with building from a kit, but does address your specific question, down in Step 27.

Several players recommend a height about the thickness of a dime at the first fret, and about the thickness of a nickel at the seventh fret. The general strategy recommended is to bring the bridge and saddle a little bit at a time until you find a height that works for you.

---

***NB***: [Original link is dead](http://mountaindulcimer.ning.com/forum/topics/string-height).